# How to set useUnsafeHeaderParsing in code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am getting the following exception:

The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF

From this question:

> [HttpWebRequestError: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491841/httpwebrequesterror-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-response)

I understand that I need to set useUnsafeHeaderParsing to True.

Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse(); //exception is thrown here
```

useUnsafeHeaderParsing is a property of HttpWebRequestElement class.

How do I integrate it in the above code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to set this is in your web.config, inside `<system.net>` section, like this:

```
<system.net> 
  <settings> 
   <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" /> 
  </settings> 
</system.net>
```

If, for some reason, you do not want to do it from your config, you could do it from code by prgrammatically setting your config settings. See  [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/ff098248-551c-4da9-8ba5-358a9f8ccc57/) for an example.

Comment: how this code add to "app.config" in c# webform application ?

Comment: I use `httpClient.PostAsync`. I get ***ServerProtocolViolation Error***. I set `useUnsafeHeaderParsing` to ***true***.

Now I get ***ArgumetOutOfRangeException***:    `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage..ctor(HttpStatusCode statusCode)`

Comment: I attempted this solution with a c# 7.1 console app, adding it to app.config, but it did not resolve the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in .Net core or how do i deal with some unsafe headers returned by a server in .Net Core?

Comment: Wow, finding this answer after reading about [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.configuration.httpwebrequestelement.useunsafeheaderparsing?view=netframework-4.8). Never expected this might still be required by someone in framework 4.8.
Though it does help to address the issue asked, so fair enough. But one "but", about the paragraph in the docslink: 
_Setting this property to true has security implications, so it should only be done if backward compatibility with a server is required._

I'm curious what would be the best next thing in this case!

Answer (score 30):

As Edwin has pointed out you need to set the useUnsafeHeaderParsing attribute in your web.config or app.config file. If you really want to change the value dynamically at runtime, then you'll have to resort to reflection as the value is buried in an instance of `System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal` and not publicly accessible.

Here is a code example (based on the info found [here](http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/dealing-with-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-sectionresponsestatusline/)) that does the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace UnsafeHeaderParsingSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Enable UseUnsafeHeaderParsing
            if (!ToggleAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing(true))
            {
                // Couldn't set flag. Log the fact, throw an exception or whatever.
            }

            // This request will now allow unsafe header parsing, i.e. GetResponse won't throw an exception.
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8000");
            var response = request.GetResponse();

            // Disable UseUnsafeHeaderParsing
            if (!ToggleAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing(false))
            {
                // Couldn't change flag. Log the fact, throw an exception or whatever.
            }

            // This request won't allow unsafe header parsing, i.e. GetResponse will throw an exception.
            var strictHeaderRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8000");
            var strictResponse = strictHeaderRequest.GetResponse();
        }

        // Enable/disable useUnsafeHeaderParsing.
        // See http://o2platform.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/dealing-with-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-sectionresponsestatusline/
        public static bool ToggleAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing(bool enable)
        {
            //Get the assembly that contains the internal class
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SettingsSection));
            if (assembly != null)
            {
                //Use the assembly in order to get the internal type for the internal class
                Type settingsSectionType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal");
                if (settingsSectionType != null)
                {
                    //Use the internal static property to get an instance of the internal settings class.
                    //If the static instance isn't created already invoking the property will create it for us.
                    object anInstance = settingsSectionType.InvokeMember("Section",
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { });
                    if (anInstance != null)
                    {
                        //Locate the private bool field that tells the framework if unsafe header parsing is allowed
                        FieldInfo aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing = settingsSectionType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                        if (aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing != null)
                        {
                            aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing.SetValue(anInstance, enable);
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this to a .Net Framework application some time ago, and it works. We're switching that app to .Net Standard 2.1, and System.Net.dll is not supported. Has anyone tried to solve this problem for a .Net Standard or .Net Core application?

Comment: @pwrgreg007 Did you get solution for .Net Core?

Comment: @PowerStar The problem we were seeing was not present when running in .Net Core. The fix we used for .Net Framework was not needed. I don't work there anymore so I cannot provide any other information. Perhaps header parsing rules were loosened in .Net Core.

Answer (score 2):

If you did't want use Reflection, you can try this code (System.Configuration.dll reference):

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net.Configuration;

var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var settings = (SettingsSection)config.GetSection("system.net/settings");
settings.HttpWebRequest.UseUnsafeHeaderParsing = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.net/settings");
```

Comment: Is this change permanent, or does it only apply to the current request?

Comment: Thanks for this helped our scenario where we have called plugins not a full app where we do not have config files.