# Allow UnsafeHeaderParsing in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mjpeg

I'm trying to get **MJPEG** stream from *Vivotek* camera to *Windows Phone 7*.

For this camera I need to set **UnsafeHeaderParsing** to **true**. I wrote similar appliction for win forms and to set this is easy using app.config file or in code,
 like fo example here [how to set useUnsafeHeaderParsing in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424144/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-in-code).

But I didn't find solution for Windows Phone and I'm afraid that there isn't one. 
Does any workaround exists?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit extreme... If you simply can't access the IP cams server from windows phone your going to need a middle man...

There are a bunch of options you could make a basic web service host it anywhere. Have the phone user register their device, provide the IP they want to watch, and any other info you need.

The phone would then connect providing its device id and the service would pull in the steam from the camera take the data and return it to the connected client with "safe" headers.

I have to admit it seems like a lot of overhead but it does sound like fun to write ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this would solve the problem, but for me is little bit overkill. I was hoping to find some easy way to achieve this, but probably it doesn't exists.