# System.Net.WebExeption CR must be followed by LF

Tags: c#, web, httpresponse

I am using this code for read content from URL:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
        using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
        {
            var html = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            return html;
        }
```

+ In app.config I have:

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

In my pc - where I code the program it work nice, but when I make exe file and try to run on my webserver I am getting error:

```
The server commited a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF
```

How can I fix this error.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF, In WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759349/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responseheader-detail-cr-must)

Comment: Poosible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759349/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responseheader-detail-cr-must

Comment: None of the above links helped even I have the same problem here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469956/file-is-downloading-through-visual-studio-but-not-through-exe#46469956

Answer (score 0):

USE This

```
if (res.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Vary"))
    {
        res.Headers["Vary"] = "Accept";
    }
    else
    {
        res.Headers.Add("Vary", "Accept");
    }
```