# File is downloading through visual studio but not through .exe

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Am getting the below error when I try to download the a `.pdf` file from a url through my `.exe` file.

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader
>   Detail=CR must be followed by LF

but the same is getting downloaded when I try to debug the code from visual studio. I am totally lost, no clue of whats going on. Can somebody tell me what could be the problem

My `App.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

`useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"` is the obvious fix that everyone is stating on internet unfortunately it is not working

Here is my webclient code

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient {
    private CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
    private string lastPage;

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
        if (address.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps) {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            // allows for validation of SSL conversations
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        }
        WebRequest R = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (R is HttpWebRequest) {
            HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)R;
            wr.CookieContainer = cc;
            if (lastPage != null) {
                wr.Referer = lastPage;
            }
        }
        lastPage = address.ToString();
        return R;
    }
}
```

**Update :** My `.exe` was able to download most of the url's except few. Consider I have 4 url's :`A,B,C and D`. My visual studio was able to download files from all 4 urls' but my `.exe` download's file from first 3 url's. For url, `D` it throws

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader
>   Detail=CR must be followed by LF

**Update 2 :**  I was trying to trace `D` url using fiddler. When I ran the `D` url from browser to download the file, I got the below header and file was **downloaded**. Also note that `D` url is **redirected** to another url before downloading

```
CONNECT www.loim.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.loim.com:443
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
```

When I tried to downlaod the file from `D` url using `.exe` I got the below header

```
CONNECT www.loim.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.loim.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

For some reason the `User-Agent` is that the problem ?

**Update3:** `dir /s /b` of the bin\debug

```
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\app.publish
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.application
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.exe
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.exe.config
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.exe.manifest
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.pdb
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.vshost.application
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.vshost.exe
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.vshost.exe.config
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\CLImport.vshost.exe.manifest
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\FED.Business.Collection.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\FED.Business.Collection.pdb
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\FED.Data.Collection.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\FED.Data.Collection.pdb
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\FED.DataSource.Utilities.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\FED.DataSource.Utilities.pdb
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\GemBox.Spreadsheet.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\Ignored
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\itextsharp.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\Processed
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\tt.text
C:\Pradeep\TFS\proj\bin\Debug\app.publish\CLImport.exe
```

Comment: Are You using different environments? Problem seems to be in `newline`. Look at this art: [NewLine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) especially at **CR+LF** and **LF+CR**.

Comment: @p__d - No am using trying to it download it in same environment thats the weirdest part. **"Problem seems to be in newline"**  can you expand, I didn't get it

Comment: I educated in this field and it's not exactly as i wrote about that `newline`. Three more path I can hit. First, do You have `web.config` also instead of `app.config`? Second, try with `release mode` to run .exe file. Third, download some `sniffer` and lookup what's in `response header`.

Comment: @jessehouwing - My question is, if there is a problem in code then how come in Visual studio I was able to download the file

Comment: @jessehouwing - Updated.. is that what you are asking for ? I am sql guy my new company makes me to work in c# so please excuse me for asking some lame questions

Comment: @jessehouwing - sorry I cannot share the url. *are you certain the app.congif is correctly being transformed into MyApp.exe.config* how to check that

Comment: @jessehouwing - It is same my App.config file in both Debug and Release

Comment: what happens if you download A, D, B, C instead of A,B,C,D, does D still fail or C - the last one?

Comment: @LeoMuller - Any case it is failing. I tried to download only `D` still it fails

Comment: This self-contained example shows that the code you have doesn't cause the problem and that the config file works as it is intended. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pgbuq2b9v48lev/ConsoleApp5.7z?dl=0 Maybe you can catch a fiddler trace of the communication so we can really raed along with what you are seeing.

Comment: @jessehouwing - I tried to get the trace using fiddler, check the update2. If you want any other info from fiddler tell me I will add

Comment: @jessehouwing - updated dude

Comment: @jessehouwing - If you dont mind, can you please say how to explicitly add user-Agent in code

Comment: Which directory are you running the exe from when you get the error? `CLImport.exe.config` needs to be in that directory. Just pointing that out since it looks like you could be publishing the exe with ClickOnce without the configuration file.

Comment: @UlfKristiansen - .exe will be called through cmd prompt. We will not publish it. But the folder that contains the `.exe` which will be called does not have `CLImport.exe.config`

Comment: @UlfKristiansen - Are kidding me damn it worked when I copy pasted the `CLImport.exe.config` to the folder from which my `.exe` will be called. Just awesome. Please post it as answer I will mark it as answer and give the bounty

Comment: @jessehouwing - Thanks a bunch for all your help. It did work by placing the `CLImport.exe.config` file in folder which has my `.exe`

Comment: Ok, done, glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [application configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/#application-configuration-files) needs to be in the same folder as the `.exe`. When you deploy `CLImport.exe` you should also deploy `CLImport.exe.config` to that folder.