# The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF in C# Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am using C# HttpClient to call the GET web service. However, I am encountering this **InnerException : The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF
in.**

I tried using WebClient as well, but it had the same issue. The Solution to set 
useUnsafeHeaderParsing is not an option for me.

I used Fiddler to debug, it shows 200 status code with the returned data.
My take on this is the issue is not with the request but with the GetAsync method.

I not am able to make any further progress in solving it.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
       var builder = new UriBuilder("http://url/abc/xyz?..");
       builder.Port = -1;
       var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
       query["param_1_key"] = "param_1";
       query["param_2_key"] = "param_2";
       query["param3_key"] = "param_3_value";
       builder.Query = query.ToString();
       string url = builder.ToString();

       client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


       var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password");
       var str = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

       response = client.GetAsync(builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri).Result;
}
```

Comment: So the server you’re calling is returning invalid data, but the provided mitigation is “not an option for you”. What kind of solution are you expecting to find?

Comment: Fiddler and postman get the exact same data, i dont see anything wrong with data unless i am missing any hidden chars. the stacktrace points to Task class. Is there anyway to look at the returned data before task class does the processing?

Comment: Are you avoiding "useUnsafeHeaderParsing" because it affects all web requests, not just the individual one you're making?
If you want to get really hacky, you should be able to make an HttpGet request using TcpClient. It won't be fun, but you'll get more granular control over how it handles such things.

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424144/how-to-set-useunsafeheaderparsing-in-code