# Strange object disposed exception on HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, web

I am working on a program that automatically queries a website every 5 seconds. It has been working fine for the last few days, but today when I simply restarted it, it keeps throwing `System.ObjectDisposedException` on the line marked underneath. I should mention that accessing this URL via a browser on the same machine works fine.

**Code:**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/");

request.Method = "GET";

try
{
    // ObjectDisposedException thrown here
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) 
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string resultString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return resultString;
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // Handle it
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
System.ObjectDisposedException occurred
    _HResult=-2146232798
   _message=Cannot access a disposed object.
    HResult=-2146232798
    IsTransient=false
    Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'.
Source=System
    ObjectName=SslStream
StackTrace:
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ValidateCreateContext(Boolean isServer, String targetHost, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, X509Certificate serverCertificate, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, Boolean remoteCertRequired, Boolean checkCertRevocationStatus, Boolean checkCertName)
 InnerException:
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? I do not even access the response stream before the `using`, how can it be disposed?

**EDIT:** Added url and stack trace

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Whose is the website?

Comment: Edited for stack trace and website

Comment: What happens if you visit the URL with a browser (from the same machine)?

Comment: @stovroz The URL works fine in the browser on the same machine

Comment: Try http channel, i.e. http://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/

Comment: BTW, can you duplicate this problem every single time or is this just happening intermittenly?

Comment: Hmm - you don't actually have to close (do `using` on) the response stream here, but I didn't think doing so would be harmful.

Comment: @Khnle - Kevin Le http doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifying things a bit and just doing a:

```
WebRequest.Create("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/").GetResponse();
```

I'm getting WebException "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF", which [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491841/httpwebrequesterror-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-response) is indicative of a problem at the server end, and one (perhaps the only) way round it is to add the following to your config file:

```
<system.net> 
  <settings> 
    <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" /> 
  </settings> 
</system.net>
```

Worked for me anyway.

Comment: In fact on a different computer, I was getting the "The server committed a protocol violation" error instead of the objectdisposed. Very strange.