# Setting useUnsafeHeaderParsing for C++ WinHttp

Tags: c++, c, winapi, winhttp

I'm trying to reach a web page on an embedded device.
I'm using WinHttp on Win32.
When trying to read response I get error

> ERROR_WINHTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE
>   12152
>   The server response cannot be parsed.

But when I captured with WireShark I can see that response is coming.
So to test I wrote a simple C# program.
GetResponse was throwing exception

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader
>   Detail=CR must be followed by LF

So according to below solution I set useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true. And it worked fine.

[HttpWebRequestError: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491841/httpwebrequesterror-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-response?lq=1)

Since I can't use C# I need to find a way to set useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true for WinHttp with win32 C++

Many thanks

Comment: Talk to the vendor of the web server kindly asking them to stop violating the HTTP protocol.

Comment: the problem is that it shows on the Chrome IE and they say since it shows properly on browsers, they claim it is standard. But obviously NOT.

Answer (score 1):

I've briefly looked into the [option flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of [`WinHttpSetOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and found the following entry:

> **WINHTTP_OPTION_UNSAFE_HEADER_BLOCKING**
>       This option is reserved for internal use and should not be called.

Since the option looks linke an on/off switch I would try to do the following:

```
BOOL bResult;
BOOL bOption = FALSE;

bResult = WinHttpSetOption(hInternet, 
                           WINHTTP_OPTION_UNSAFE_HEADER_BLOCKING,
                           &bOption,
                           sizeof(bOption));
if (bResult == FALSE)
{
    /* handle error with GetLastError() */
}
```

Well but as MSDN says it's reserved for internal use and therefore the function may change in the future (or has already changed in the past). But it's worth a try... Good Luck!

Comment: I'm trying to set this but it says WINHTTP_OPTION_UNSAFE_HEADER_BLOCKING undeclared identifier. What can be the problem?

Comment: @AFgone Hmmm... I don't know. Maybe you need a newer version of the Windows SDK?

Comment: I have 7, 7.1 8 8.1 when I go to winhttp I see it is from 7.0 but in my include directories I couldn't find windows sdk path. How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the name of the option must have changed since then: with the current SDK it's `WINHTTP_OPTION_UNSAFE_HEADER_PARSING`.  Also, I verified (by examining the Assembly code directly) that:

- the option must be `DWORD`-sized
- the value of the option doesn't matter, as long as it's nonzero
- you can only *enable* unsafe parsing; trying to disable (by setting the option value to zero) causes an error to be returned

Obviously, since this undocumented, it's subject to change.