# Powershell wget protocol violation

Tags: powershell, wget

I am trying to browse a command on an embedded webserver using wget / invoke-webrequest. How can this error be avoided?

*wget : The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=CR must be followed by LF*

Already tried multiple things, for example below without success:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

When using BITS instead, this is the error I'm getting

*start-bitstransfer : The server did not return the file size. The URL might point to dynamic content. The Content-Length header is not available in 
the server's HTTP reply.*

Thanks so much for your help
Clem

Comment: So you've tried two clients: [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) (from Powershell) and [Microsoft BITS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In both cases, you get "protocol errors" from the server.  Hmmm....  Q: What happens if you run wget from the command line, or .bat file?  Q: Can you successfully talk to the server from *ANY* client?  Q: What exactly is the server supposed to be doing?  what exactly *IS* the failing response, and how is it implemented?

Comment: @paulsm4 wget is aliased to `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: That is correct, having similar issues with both. Trying to download photos from a WiFi enabled camera. The connection to the embedded server is fine. When I do this same exact thing in linux with wget it works just fine. Would prefer to use BITS though.

Comment: Q: What happens if you run wget from the command line, or .bat file?
>> Same exact error
Q: Can you successfully talk to the server from ANY client? 
>> Communication is fine, can browse the url with a browser
Q: What exactly is the server supposed to be doing? what exactly IS the failing response, and how is it implemented?
>> Download the file/picture. Embedded in WiFi Camera.

Answer (score 17):

Setting the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` delegate won't help you - SSL/TLS is *not* the protocol being referred to - the protocol violation is with regards to the **HTTP** headers (eg. long *after* TLS has been established).

There's a .NET [configuration flag called `useUnsafeHeaderParsing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491841/httpwebrequesterror-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-response) that controls whether such violations are ignored or not.

Using reflection, it can also be set from the runtime. [This Technet forum answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/8ca2eb90-63fe-4f60-9f00-344fc321383b/simple-invokewebrequest-produces-protocol-violation-when-attempting-to-xml-login-to-a-web-based?forum=winserverpowershell) give's a great example of how to do so in PowerShell, we can wrap that in a nifty function like below:

```
function Set-UseUnsafeHeaderParsing
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='Enable')]
        [switch]$Enable,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName='Disable')]
        [switch]$Disable
    )

    $ShouldEnable = $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Enable'

    $netAssembly = [Reflection.Assembly]::GetAssembly([System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection])

    if($netAssembly)
    {
        $bindingFlags = [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Static,GetProperty,NonPublic'
        $settingsType = $netAssembly.GetType('System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal')

        $instance = $settingsType.InvokeMember('Section', $bindingFlags, $null, $null, @())

        if($instance)
        {
            $bindingFlags = 'NonPublic','Instance'
            $useUnsafeHeaderParsingField = $settingsType.GetField('useUnsafeHeaderParsing', $bindingFlags)

            if($useUnsafeHeaderParsingField)
            {
              $useUnsafeHeaderParsingField.SetValue($instance, $ShouldEnable)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use like:

```
Set-UseUnsafeHeaderParsing -Enable
```

before calling `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

When using reflection I get this error which I`m not able to resolve
Exception calling "SetValue" with "2" argument(s): "Object of type 'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter' cannot be converted to type 
'System.Boolean'."