# GoPro/Powershell: Protocol violation when trying to read .json status file

Tags: json, powershell, gopro

I try to read the status file of a GoPro Hero5.

If you type "http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpcontrol/status" while connected to the GoPro-Wifi the camera responds with a json status file.

I want to get this status file with powershell, with the Invoke-RestMethod:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/status"
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The server committed a protocol violation.. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=Auf CR muss LF folgen
At line:3 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://10.5.5.9/gp/gpControl/stat ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Here is an example on what the status file should look like: https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack/blob/master/HERO4/CameraStatus.md

Any hints how to get the file with powershell would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491841/httpwebrequesterror-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-response

Comment: Thanks for the link! Works just fine!